# Powershell: Out-File

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to log all console output to a file.
    move-item D:\scripts\fileA D:\scripts\fileB -verbose -Force | Out-File D:\scripts\move.log -Append

the file is being created if it doesn't exist.
But the verbose information and eventual powershell errors are not present in this file.
How can I get this info?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pipe only captures the success output stream, not the error and verbose streams. To capture the latter as well you need to redirect it to the former:

```
Move-Item "D:\scripts\fileA" "D:\scripts\fileB" -Verbose -Force 2>&1 4>&1 |
  Out-File D:\scripts\move.log -Append
```

See [`Get-Help about_Redirection`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746) for more information.

Comment: Just to add to what Ansgar stated, this is the way both *nix and Windows systems handle output; an output stream and an error stream. Error streams are outputted immediately, in an attempt to output as much data as possible in case a crash is imminent (it is diagnostic after all, allowing one to collect logs or whatever and triage the issue); whereas the standard output stream is not so responsive. So if you want both, you have to tell it to send file descriptor 2 (stderr) to the same place as file descriptor 1 (stdout). FD 3, btw, is stdin.

Comment: There are a few more streams as well, e.g. warnings and verbose messages. Those are redirectable from within PowerShell but won't show up as separate streams to the outside world.

Comment: @ash Stdin is FD 0. File descriptors 3-9 are for additional files/output streams in [Unix shells](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) as well as in [CMD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx). In PowerShell stream 3 is for redirecting warnings, 4 is for verbose and 5 for debug output.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers oops, I meant FD 0 for stdin, thanks for catching that. Also, thanks for the other FDs, I wasnt aware of some of those.